# Why doesn't Java have a REPL?

Tags: java, scala, read-eval-print-loop

I was wondering why Java doesn't have a REPL. Is there some technical limitation? As an aside, how do REPLs actually work, what's going on with say the Scala REPL?

Comment: My first hit was javarepl.com

Comment: "how do REPLs actually work" - It's described in the name ;)

Comment: @ChrisMartin I guess I meant on a deeper runtime level, instead of the obvious..

Comment: It *is* obvious. In a Lisp or similar language, it is *literally* just `(loop (print (eval read)))`. Well, you might want to print a prompt in between and handle errors gracefully and so on, but that's basically it.

Answer (score 2):

I think they are [planning/thinking](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2601433/java-language/programmers-could-get-repl-in-official-java.html) to introduce REPL in java 9. One of the problem according to Scala author Odersky is that REPL are expression-oriented and java on the other hand is statement-oriented, so not much so much useful for Java.

Answer (score 2):

The IBM VisualAge for Java IDE had a REPL (or more precisely, a Smalltalk-style "Worksheet"), by virtue of it being written in Smalltalk and basically only a slightly modified version of the IBM VisualAge for Smalltalk IDE. However, when IBM VisualAge for Java was rewritten in Java and released under the name of IBM VisualAge for Java Micro Edition, it still kept its REPL.

And when IBM modularized IBM VisualAge for Java Micro Edition and released it as Open Source under its new name "Eclipse", it *still* kept its REPL, and it is in fact still there in the very latest version, under the name "Scrapbook page".

That one is not the only one, there are other REPLs as well, e.g. the REPL behind http://JavaREPL.Com/ is Open Source on GitHub.